# jquery autocomplete style list item on specific response value

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

can anyone please give me a code example for a jquery ui-autocomplete case:

If I get back e.g.: "no entry" as answer, I want to style the list entry (.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item a) (e.g. red).

So this is my autocomplete handler

```
$('#id').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
       $.getJSON("file.php", {
           data1: "somedata",
           data2: "somethingelse"
       }, response);
    },
    minLength:0,
    open: function() {
       $(this).attr('state', 'open')
       $(this).autocomplete("widget").css({ "width": 267 });
    },
   close: function () { $(this).attr('state', 'closed'); autocomplete_land(); },
   select: function(event, ui){ $(this).css('background-color', '#5582cb').css('color', '#fff'); }
})
.focus(function () {
   if ($(this).attr('state') != 'open') {
      $(this).autocomplete("search");
   }
});
```

This ist the jquery generated autocomplete list:

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 338px; left: 850px; display: none; width: 267px;">
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
      <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">some data</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

so when I get back „no entry“ it should be like this (red: style="color:#ff0000;")

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 338px; left: 850px; display: none; width: 267px;">
   <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
      <a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1" style="color:#ff0000;">no entry</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Many thanks already

Comment: You should provide a minimal, reproducible example of what you try and describe the expected outcome. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example